# How can I get the history of user input in C?

Tags: c, user-input

I have a simple calculator that allows me to keep entering new numbers and spits out a profit amount. But I'd like to be able to use the arrow key (up) to get the last entry.

I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// ------------------------------------------------

int main (int argCount, char *argv[]) {
    float 
        shares = atof(argv[1]),
        price = atof(argv[2]),

        // Commission fees
        fee = 4.95,

        // Total price paid (counts buy + sell commission)
        base = (price * shares) + (fee * 2),
        profit;

    printf("TOTAL BUY: %.3f\n", base);

    /**
     * Catch the input and calculate the 
     * gain based on the new input.
     */
    char sell[32];

    while (1) {
        printf(": ");
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(sell, sizeof(sell), stdin);

        profit = (atof(sell) * shares) - base;
        printf(": %.3f", profit);

        // Show [DOWN] if the estimate is negative
        if (profit < 0)
            printf("\33[31m [DOWN]\33[0m\n");

        // Show [UP] if the estimate is positive
        else printf("\33[32m [UP]\33[0m\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: The answer is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

// ------------------------------------------------

int main (int argCount, char *argv[]) {
    float 
        shares = atof(argv[1]),
        price = atof(argv[2]),

        // Commission fees
        fee = 4.95,

        // Total price paid
        base = (price * shares) + (fee * 2),
        profit;

    printf("TOTAL BUY: %.3f\n", base);

    /**
     * Catch the users input and calculate the 
     * gain based on the new input.
     *
     * This makes it easy for active traders or
     * investors to calculate a proposed gain.
     */
    char* input, prompt[100];

    for(;;) {
        rl_bind_key('\t', rl_complete);
        snprintf(prompt, sizeof(prompt), ": ");

        if (!(input = readline(prompt)))
            break;

        add_history(input);

        profit = (atof(input) * shares) - base;
        printf(": %.3f", profit);

        // Show [DOWN] if the estimate is negative
        if (profit < 0)
            printf("\33[31m [DOWN]\33[0m\n");

        // Show [UP] if the estimate is positive
        else printf("\33[32m [UP]\33[0m\n");
        free(input);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: with the readline library: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [GNU readline library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline), which provides line-editing and command history. [Here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) is the project's homepage. It seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use something like [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) to add that functionality natively to your application. Most people, however, just use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/).

```
$ rlwrap your_prog
```

Comment: Nice, I'll use this in the future. Thanks!